# 403 redirects doesn't work but 404 does. What's wrong, what can I do?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-403, errordocument

First post around here !

I'm currently working on a website with Wamp and I am having an issue with 403 redirects. I would like to redirect all these 403 errors to a custom page.
In my .htaccess (the file is in www/project with my index.php) I have this two lines:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /project/views/error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /project/views/error.php
```

The thing is the 404 errors are perfectly redirected to the error.php page so it seems the path to the custom page is correct but it doesn't work for the 403 errors and still displays me the Apache default error page :

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access (a URL that return 403) on this server.

Please can you help me to understand what's happening because I really dont know why it doesn't work and I've seen lot of similar questions but no good answers yet.

Thank you

Comment: What _causes_ those 403 errors? Is it the web server itself, or is it a status that is generated inside your application?

Comment: _“(Hello everyone ! I don't know why my Hello is removed ) ”_ - because we want to focus on the technical details of the problem, and keep the “clutter” that could distract from those to a minimum. https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior: _“Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.”_

Comment: Several causes, I wanted to test the 403 errors so I did it different ways. I put in url something like localhost/project/"" or localhost/project/... and I got 403 which is probably   normal because it is invalid characters I guess but I would like a redirect in this case. I also created a php file with a 403 error in it. I just want to redirect the 403 errors whatever is the cause, is that possible ? I saw on multiple websites that what I did with the url was returning to an error custom page.

Comment: If your own PHP script is already being executed, then this is not a 403 _from the web server’s perspective_ any more. You are completely responsible for the response, when your script at some point decides that access should be forbidden. After issuing the 403 status code, you could _include_ your `/project/views/error.php` script now from within your other script.

Comment: Yeah for the created php file ok. But it was just to tell you I did it different ways and that I want 403 being redirected whatever the cause, It's more about the url case that I have this problem cause there is no script behind

Comment: The default error message you are getting from Apache, does that include any additional message about the specified error document not being readable or something?

Comment: Well, I knew you would ask that 'cause I saw on many other topics that they had an additional message but I actually don't. I searched in the apache error log  they said : The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:55172] AH00127: Cannot map GET /project/%22%22 HTTP/1.1 to file. 
I suppose it is because of invalid characters and that there is no file that exists with this name. But why the 403 error is not being redirected then ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I feel like I'm not clear enough. Maybe it is normal that there is a 403 error and I dont mind. What I want is to fix the redirect not the cause of the 403 because if someday there is an other 403 , I want to be sure it redirects the user to my custom error page.

Comment: I think I found the solution here :  https://serverfault.com/questions/981840/custom-403-error-page-is-not-displayed-when-wildcard-characters-are-in-the-url 

It says that the 403 error is triggered before the .htaccess and you need to put the DocumentError in the server config or virtualhost. I added the line in httpd-vhosts.conf and now it works great ! localhost/project/"" or localhost/project/... is well redirected to my custom page ! Does it seems to be a good answer to you ? Even in terms of security, no problem ? Happy to finally found what was the problem !

Comment: Ah, yes, that explains it, Apache filters out such syntactically invalid URLs before it even gets to evaluating the directory content and with that the .htaccess.